# ExAws S3 - Get URL of uploaded file

Tags: elixir

The Elixir library [ExAws](https://github.com/CargoSense/ex_aws) S3 module has a `put_object` method that allows you to execute a file upload.

```
%{path: filepath, filename: filename} = %Plug.Upload{...}
{:ok, contents} = File.read(filepath)
time = DateTime.utc_now() |> DateTime.to_unix
path = "#{Mix.env}/#{time}/#{filename}"

@bucket |> ExAws.S3.put_object(path, contents) |> ExAws.request
=> {:ok, %{body: "", headers: [{"x-amz-id-2", "someid="}, {"x-amz-request-id", "someid"}, {"Date", "Thu, 16 Feb 2017 19:43:01 GMT"}, {"ETag", "\"sometag\""}, {"Content-Length", "0"}, {"Server", "AmazonS3"}], status_code: 200}}
```

I have not been able to figure out the URL to my uploaded file, however. Using this library, how can I get the URL of my uploaded file?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `ex_aws` doesn't provide this option. I used it with combination with `arc` and arc basically generates the urls on its own, but sometimes they are invalid. Best solution is to check manually what urls your files have and based on that build your own `get_url` function. I found myself very iritated by arc and I seriously think about creating my own S3 upload / download library.

Answer (score 3):

In general, a file in S3 follows the pattern:

```
s3://<bucket-name>/<file-key>
```

where the file-key can include directories and the like.  That's when using the S3 protocol for a tool like the AWS cli.

However, for HTTP type access, the pattern is

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket-name>/<file-key>
```

But only if you've enabled static hosting in the bucket and have allowed access to the file-key to whomever should get it.  This isn't the default.  You'll need to either manually set the bucket and file to be readable via HTTPS via the console or through the toolkit.  It looks like that can be handled with some combination of `put_bucket_website`, `put_bucket_acl` and/or `put_object_acl`.

Answer (score 0):

The URL pattern is `https://{bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/{key}`

```
url = "https://{}.s3.amazonaws.com/{}".format("your-bucket-id","object-key")
```